# Asp.NET Core 3.1 middleware’s and authorization handlers order

Tags: asp.net-core, middleware, asp.net-authorization, asp.net-core-middleware

I have a question about middleware’s and authorization handlers execution order. In my ASP.NET Core 3.1 I have middleware’s registered in that order

- A, UseAuthentication, UseAuthorisation, B, UseHealthChecks

But when actual request is executed I have this order

- A, AuthenticationHandler, B, AuthorisationHandler

When I change order of B and healthcheck in registration to

- A, UseAuthentication, UseAuthorisation, **UseHealthChecks, B**

When executing request I have this order

- A, AuthenticationHandler, AuthorisationHandler, B

Can someone explain why order is in that way?

UPDATE:
I have created test repo https://github.com/bigdnf/Playgraund2/blob/master/WebApplication6/WebApplication6/Startup.cs

but I find out one thing. My healthcheck have UseEndpoint inside and no middleware was executed after it so this is clear now. But the question is now only why authorisation middleware is executed after all middleware's. Can I execute middleware after it or this is by design in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Could you please post the details codes about your B middleware?  I have created a test demo on my side, it works well.

Comment: @BrandoZhang I have created test repo - some things are clear now but there is one question left.

Answer (score 0):

According to your test project, I found you don't add the Authorize attribute in the WeatherForecast controller, that means the Authorize middleware will not call the AuthorisationHandler HandleRequirementAsync to handle the request.

But the MVC filter will call the HandleRequirementAsync method after C middleware.

You could see how it work by modifying the logs level to trace.

[image]

If you add the Authorize attribute in the WeatherForecast controller, you could see the middleware execute the HandleRequirementAsync before the C.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[Authorize("channel-policy")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
```

Log:

[image]